# Superfish-style dropdown menu won't show in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, superfish

I've disabled the superfish js for now so it's pure CSS.  The URL is http://pittsculture.studiotwo.com/category/outdoors-recreation/.  It looks fine in FF and Chrome.  But, believe it or not, IE has a problem with the dropdowns (e.g., under Outdoors and Recreation).  Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `#main-nav`, you need to remove the `filter` rule. The `filter` is causing Internet Explorer to behave as though you have applied `overflow: hidden` to the element.

Now your dropdown menu works, but it's lost the gradient.

You can add the gradient back in a way that won't cause the same problem by adding the same `filter` you just removed to `#menu-category-navigation`. As far as I can tell, it looks identical.

Comment: Thanks...you're right about the filter rule being the cause of the problem.  Unfortunately, if I move the filter to the underlying UL, the gradient no longer fills the width of the navigation.  I just removed it altogether from IE.  When will they get their act together?

Comment: In IE9, you can [make gradients using SVG](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/), which is an improvement over using the `filter` property. If you're happy with this answer, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it.

Comment: I'll take a look at SVG but I'm not sure it's worth it with IE's market share dwindling like it is.  A gradient isn't crucial.

Comment: Agreed — the filter CSS rule causes many flickering drop-down issues in ie. Thanks for the fix!!!!